# Как правильно оформить сервер на nodejs express на виртуальном удаленном сервере?

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, apache, сервер, express

Я в отчаянии.

На данный момент у меня есть сервер express.js, который просто отправляет в ответ на get запрос НЕстатичную страничку через res.sendFile.

Это работает через http, но не работает через https, и поэтому я думаю, что это неправильно.

Как на самом деле это нужно делать? Разместить страничку в var/www/html_public, запустить сервер на другом порте, и просто делать запросы к серверу на этом порту?

Answer (score 0):

Для https нужно добавить сертификат на сервер (можно сгенерировать самому)

```
const ssl = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/cert.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('cert/privkey.pem')
};
```

И далее использовать ssl

```
const server = https.createServer(ssl, app);
```

Ну и ваш код.